# Cannot find the scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a very bad experienced about the `scanner` because I am using `GUI` and `JOptionPane`. So I am not be able to do the program's interns of `scanner` because. I am new to it so Please help me, "cannot find the `scanner`". This is my code so far .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class MultiplicationTables{
     public static void main(String args[]){
          int n, c;
          System.out.println("Enter an integer to print its multiplication table");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          n = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Multiplication table of "+n+" is :-");

          for ( c = 1 ; c <= 10 ; c++ )
             System.out.println(n+"*"+c+" = "+(n*c));
     }
}
```

Comment: i have an error of that code sir

Comment: Can u paste the error

Comment: then write your error !

Comment: Your code doesn't have errors. It's waiting for you to enter the input.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol Scanner line 9

Comment: cannot resolve symbol class Scanner

Comment: hmm i think my version is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If your Java is not version 1.5 or above, Scanner class is not provided.

go to command promt

type "java -version"

check your version.If you have outdated just update. Problem shoud be fixed..
and make sure your IDE or the JDK actually use it.

Code that you have here provided is correct so you can use it after you fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First import is redundant.

```
import java.io.*; // you can remove it
```

Scanner is a class in java.util package.
Check weather you have properly set your jdk path in your ide, or in your system. 
Depends on system that you use:
Windows: Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->Path check weather there is your path to jdk.

UNIX in console print 'echo $PATCH' and check that if you have there jdk path properly added.

And then you can check your version of java independent to system in console writing

```
java --version
```